# Installing Ubuntu on my Desktop parallel to Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

I have a desktop which is running on Windows XP SP3. I want to install Ubuntu so that I can use either of the OS. This is mainly to learn and get acclimatized to using Ubuntu before fully converting to Ubuntu. Can I download Ubuntu directly and start installation as shown in your website? Or do I need the help of an expert to do so? Will all my Windows XP installations work properly even after installing Ubuntu? 
Regards!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Download the iso file and burn it to a cd or make a bootable pendrive and install the ubuntu.

make separete partition for ubuntu which s available in the installation wizard(something else option) and create partition for ubuntu
(ext4) and swap(swap) 
or you can choose install ubuntu alongside with windows option in the wizard.